# Messages: Setting to Always Display Time Stamp?

Tags: macos, iphone, messages

Is it possible to display the Time Stamp of messages by default in both the Desktop Messages app, and the mobile app?

This is the default view:

[image]

Obviously, the time stamps are viewable by hovering the mouse over a message for the desktop version, or swiping left in the mobile app.

But having them always displayed without the mouseover popup like this:

[image]

http://www.macissues.com/2014/04/28/view-timestamps-in-messages-on-your-mac-and-iphone/

Would make far more sense. There doesn't seem to be a setting to always show the time stamp in either Messages.App or Messages for iOS, and I'm aware this doesn't seem to be an Apple-supported option, but perhaps it would be achievable through Terminal or an add-in.

Answer (score 0):

They are displayed by default, as well in the left navigation panel as in the messages list on the right side....

Comment: That shows when the most recent message was delivered. To view when each message was delivered, you must: "hover the mouse over a message for the desktop version, or swipe left in the mobile app."